# Finding a maximal isotropic subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra

I have the following question:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex vector space.
For a given bilinear form $(,): V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, a subspace $W$ of $V$ is called isotropic with respect to $(,)$ if $(w,w) =0$ for all $w\in W$.

My questions are that：

(1). Is it true that the dimension is invariant? (I mean, it is a constant for all isotropic subspaces).

(2). How can we describe this dimension in terms of any information of $(,)$?

(3). How can we find a maximal isotropic subspace?
Thanks very much!

Comment: I think there can be many different totally isotropic subspaces (in fact, the flags of these subspaces are the simplices of the Tits building of the special orthogonal group if I'm not wrong here). But the dimension of a maximal totally isotropic subspace is an invariant of the form called the Witts index (which is the rank of the special orthogonal group). However, I would be very interested in a concrete example or a general idea on how to compute all the totally isotropic subspaces.

Comment: @abenthy: You should see proposition 2.6 of [this thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0401221.pdf) and also my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750734/on-proposition-2-6-gualtieri-thesis-generalized-complex-geometry). Thanks